# Specific font_face based on syntax in Sublime Text 2

Tags: windows, python, ide, sublime-text-2

Is it possible to display a specific font_face for each individual syntax language setting in Sublime Text 2?  For example:

```
"php" : { "font_face" : "Droid Sans Mono" },
"c#" : { "font_face" : "Courier New" },
"javascript" : { "font_face" : "monospace" }
```

Couldn't find much about the font_face setting in ST2 other than how to change it globally.  My job requires me to jump around a lot of different language files and think this would make them easier to distinguish on the fly.  I like my color scheme and want to keep that the way it is, but unfortunately it doesn't quite differ enough for me to be able to pick out the languages quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Open a filetype for which you want to change the font. Then in the menu select **Preferences** > **Settings-More** > **Syntax Specific - User**.

In that file (which will be created if it not already exists), enter you specific font-needs. For instance:

```
{
  "font_face": "Broadway",
  "font_size": 12
}
```